# Column / Text - Go to the next line

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, grid

I want to create a `navigation menu` with multiple `columns / rows`. And for the `parent element` i have a fixed `height`. How to make the `columns / text` that overflow the height goes on the next line ? see the `visual representation` below.

[image]

Comment: Look for `column-count` it may help you to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `columns` property for auto column layouts.

```
columns: 4;
```

```css
.container {
  columns: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
```

You can set width for columns if you want. How many columns fit with 300px, it puts that much. For example 4 columns fit on a 1200px screen.

```
columns: 300px auto;
```

```css
.container {
  columns: 300px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<h6>Title</h6>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
<li>Some Category</li>
```

You can find more information from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns).